# c# decode HTML chars in email

Tags: c#, email, decode

An array contains an email. This e-mail looks at the moment like:

> testmail%40mail.de

I'm searching for an methode to get this e-mail to readable format for humans. I know everybody would be able to identify '%40' after some time, but I would need to get for example in this case 'testmail@mail.de'
I found the solution to use "System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()". I use .Net4.0 but there was no readable output using the methode above (output was the same one). I hope to get an easy way to solve this.

Comment: Did you try UrlDecode?

Answer (score 2):

The email address is URL encoded therefore you are required to URL decode it.

.NET has the following utilities available for you to do this:

```
HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(string) or HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string)
```